# Trumbowyg lightweight rich editor svg icons not showing up

Tags: javascript, svg, trumbowyg

I was wondering if anyone has dealt with this plugin: http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/

I believe I'm doing everything right. The only thing is that svg icons are not showing up?

```
$('#trumbowyg-demo').trumbowyg({
  svgPath: 'my-path-to-icons' //doesn't event work
});
```

Is the icons.svg file correct -- from the download?

This is what's showing up

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My problem was down to the fact I was using an ajaxPrefilter. Disabling this for the icons.svg request solved it. Try putting a breakpoint inside the following get method in the trumbowyg js file and see if the ajax request completes. That's how I found the solution to my issue

```
$.get(svgPath, function (data) {
    div.innerHTML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data.documentElement);
});
```